# How to get type of implicitly typed array with roslyn?

Tags: .net, vb.net, roslyn

Imagine the following VB.NET code:

```
Dim a
a = {1, 2}
```

If I discover such scenario I would like the `a` to become strongly typed, i.e. `Dim a As Integer()`. `{1, 2}` itself is a `CollectionInitializerSyntax`, lets refer to it as to `initExpr`.

The question is - why can't I get type info of the `initExpr` using:

```
model.GetTypeInfo(initExpr).Type
```

where model is semantic model of the document in which `a = {1, 2}` expression resides. Issue can be seen also using syntax tree visualizer, just place the cursor on the initializer, right click the `initExpr` and choose "View TypeSymbol", it shows just blank page.

I reckon there must be a way to do this as implicitly typed arrays work just fine like this:

```
Dim a = {1, 2}
```

Placing a cursor on the `a` in the Visual Studio shows it is of type `Integer()`. So bottom line is, how can I get the type info in roslyn for the `initExpr`.

Comment: Can you get the type of `a` instead of the array expression?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel unfortunately not as i also have to cover function parameters, i.e. there could be a call to function foo like `foo({1,2})` where there is an untyped parameter in the `foo`'s signature which I would like to type.

Comment: I'm not familiar with VB.NET so I can't comment on those intrinsics. You might want to consider a different approach as it seems like you're trying to do fairly distinctive things at the same time. One of these is a variable declaration while the other is an argument.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel thanks for your input, however, I don't think these things are so distinctive - bottom line is I need to find out the type of `{1,2}` no matter where is it used. It appears to work flawlessly in C# for `new[] {1,2}` and hence my question.

Comment: For anyone interested, this is a bug in roslyn and progress of its fix can be tracked [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/11933).